# Синхронизация PWA приложений | JS

Tags: javascript, pwa

Есть PWA приложение с WebSocket. Пока пользователь в сети, за обновление данных отвечает сокет. С этим проблем нет. Но есть проблема с синхронизацией этих самых данных после потери сети/закрытой вкладки. Если на винде я могу отслеживать сеть, то на том же маке, если судить по консолям, даже при закрытой крышке происходит соединение с сетью время от времени (что уже усложняет задачу). Поэтому правильное определение последнего онлайна уже затрудняется. Для оффлайна вкладки делаю записи в localstorage, а потом по ней синхронизирую.

Может кто-нибудь подсказать, где посмотреть правильный способ синхронизации PWA приложений? Может ссылку на книгу или статьи какие.

Comment: Ответы на данный вопрос скорее всего будут основаны на личном, *субъективном* опыте, стоит исправить вопрос так, чтобы ответы на него были исключительно *объективные*. Подробнее [в справке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Вопрос можно отредактировать кнопкой «[edit]».

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для синхронизации данных в PWA приложениях после потери соединения можно использовать следующие подходы:

1)**Service Workers** - позволяют перехватывать запросы и обращаться к кэшу или IndexedDB в офлайне. Можно реализовать логику синхронизации в service worker.

2)**IndexedDB** - хранилище данных на клиенте. Можно сохранять данные из сокета в IndexedDB, а затем синхронизировать с сервером.

3)**Background Sync API** - позволяет отложенную синхронизацию данных когда появится подключение.

4)**Паттерн Optimistic UI** - отображать локальные изменения сразу, а синхронизировать в фоне.

Полезные ресурсы:

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync

https://web.dev/offline-cookbook/

*Основные идеи*: использовать Service Workers и IndexedDB для офлайн логики, Background Sync для отложенной синхронизации, Optimistic UI чтобы не блокировать интерфейс.

Надеюсь, что поможет